# Grab two latest records of group by platform and semver

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group, psql

For every pairing of `platform` and `semver` I'm trying to to get the second newest record as a way to support the previous app version to latest, at all times.

Here's my schema:

```
id, platform, semver, name
```

Some sample data:

[image]

I would like the query to return:

```
papapal, ios,     1.0.2
papapal, android, 1.0.2
foobar,  ios,     1.4.0
foobar,  android, 1.4.0
```

Notice how it's not the latest record, but the second latest record.

I can sort by semver using, but the grabbing second latest for each app is tripping me up.

```
SELECT id, semver
FROM   app_versions
ORDER  BY string_to_array(semver, '.')::int[];
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the nubers between dots always are one digit only, you can use window functions as follows:

```
select platform, name, semver
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by platform, name order by semver desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 2
```

On the other hand, if you have versions numbers like `'1.12.2'` (which is greater than `'1.2.1'`), then you can indeed turn them to arrays of integers for ordering:

```
select platform, name, semver
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by platform, name order by string_to_array(semver, '.')::int[] desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 2
```